# How to use the same initialCommands with and without ammonite

Tags: sbt, ammonite

I work on a project and I want to let the choice of using ammonite at each developer.

So I have to share the `initialCommands` to avoid dups.

Here are my current solution.

```
val initCommands = s""" val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext("local", "shell"); val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc); import sqlContext.implicits._; import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ """

val escaped = initCommands.replace("\"", "\\\"")

initialCommands in console := initCommands

initialCommands in (Test, console) := s"""ammonite.Main(predef = "$escaped").run()"""
```

First issue is that `initCommands` have to be on one line.

Is there a better way ?